# return (preg_replace($profanity, $repl_code, $html))

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I'm trying to update an older script. None of my `preg_replace_callback` variations are working, though. Does anyone know a solution?

This is the original code:

```
public static function filterHTML($html) {

    // a simple preg_replace will do for now to see it actually works
    // turn the PA::$config->profanity array into an array of regexp
    $profanity = array();
    foreach (PA::$config->profanity as $i => $w) {
        $profanity[] = "!\b(" . $w . ")\b!ie";
        // the \b ensures that we are dealing with szand alone 
        // occurences of the word or phrase
        // /ie case insensitive and run replacement as code
    }
    $repl_code = "ProfanityFilter::replace('$1')";
    return (preg_replace($profanity, $repl_code, $html));
}
```

Comment: Why nobody asks for a script to add profanities?

Comment: Your question is eventually a duplicate cause there are a lot of questions about how to replace the `e` modifier with `preg_replace_callback`. A better approach than using an array (if you always need the same replacement) is to build an alternation like `\b(prof1|prof2|...)\b` to parse the string only once.

Comment: *With an array, the string is parsed once for each item.*

Comment: http://banbuilder.com/  and similar things offering prebuilt "solutions" may be worth a look. Also http://www.codingforums.com/post-a-php-snippet/135849-super-simple-bad-word-filter.html (might need to replace short tags in this script)  A short script http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/132754-solved-profanity-filter/